# Angularjs uiGmapGoogleApi info window not working?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

i have used uiGmapGoogleMapApi **NOT WORKING** array of marker infowindow. Can you Help me? no issue is comming but not working

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
    <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" idkey="markers.id" coords="'coords'" click="
                                onClick()" events="markers.events" >
                                    <ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions" closeClick="closeClick()">
                                        <div>{{title}}</div>
                            </ui-gmap-window>
                                </ui-gmap-markers>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Script.file

```
angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
        $scope.map = {center: {latitude: 40.1451, longitude: -99.6680 }, zoom: 4 }
        $scope.options = {scrollwheel: false};
        $scope.markers = [{
            coords: {
                latitude: 40.1451,
                longitude: -99.6680
            },
            id: 0
        }
        ];

        $scope.windowOptions = {
            visible: false
        };

        $scope.onClick = function() {
            $scope.windowOptions.visible = !$scope.windowOptions.visible;
        };

        $scope.closeClick = function() {
            $scope.windowOptions.visible = false;
        };

        $scope.title = "Window Title!";
    });
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/x1raMXK5dpYW84I76lhb?p=preview)

Comment: Define _"not working"_ more precisely please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my issue. [Documenation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api)

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" data-smart-map-instance="demoMap" options="options">

                                <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" idkey="markers.id" coords="'coords'" click="
                                onClick()" events="markers.events" >

                                    <ui-gmap-windows show="show" closeClick="closeClick()">
                                         <div ng-non-bindable>{{id}}</div>
                                    </ui-gmap-windows>
                                </ui-gmap-markers>

                                </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

script file

```
$scope.markers = []; 
   var data={
                                id: i,
                                coords: {
                                    latitude: 11.897890789,
                                    longitude: 78.6786876.lng
                                },
                                data: 'house'
                        };
                        $scope.markers.push(data);
$scope.map = {
                           center: {
                                latitude: $scope.markers[0].coords.latitude,
                                longitude: $scope.markers[0].coords.longitude
                            },
                        zoom: 9
                    };

                    $scope.options = {
                            scrollwheel: true,
                            disableDefaultUI: true,
                            zoomControl: true, 
                            scaleControl: true,
                           // streetViewControl: true
                    };
```